# How to determine if text exists inside parentheses?

Tags: vba, excel

I have string with parentheses and a value inside the parentheses.

For example: Data(redundant)

I want to look at the string, with two conditions.

1. If it has "read" or "write" inside the parentheses.
   For example: Data(write)
2. If other that "read" and "write"
   For example: Data(redundant) or Data(&explore)

Another form of the string would be: Data(), which does not fulfill either of the conditions.

The problem is when my string is Data(), it goes in condition 2.

```vb
If InStr(1, string, "read") <> 0 Or InStr(1, string, "write") <> 0 Then
    Call CleanStr(string)
ElseIf string Like "*(*" Or string Like "*(&*" Then
    argTemp = Split(string, "(")
    arg = "(" & argTemp(1)
End If
```

Comment: Can't your ElseIf condition be ...ElseIf string <> "Data()" Then...

Comment: string = Data() is just an example. string is actually dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the bracketed content out with a double split and check the length of the returned string.

```
dim bstr as string, str as string
str = "Date(read)"
bstr = split(split(str & "()", ")")(0), "(")(1)
if cbool(len(bstr)) then
    debug.print "(" & bstr ")"
end if
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I used the logic behind this to come up with what  I want. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There's one command to accomplish your task, i.e.: `Right(s, InStr(1, s, "(") + 1)`, take a look on how to use it:

```
Sub test()
Dim s As String, BetweenBrackets As String
s = "data(read)"
BetweenBrackets = Right(s, InStr(1, s, "(") + 1) 'it will return contnet in brackets WITH brackets

If BetweenBrackets = "(read)" Or BetweenBrackets = "(write)" Then
    'first condition satisfied
ElseIf Len(BetweenBrackets) > 2 Then 'if it's more than brackets
    'second condition satisfied
Else
    '...
End If


End Sub
```